# Change Hyperparameters on an ongoing simulation of TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I wonder if it is possible to change some hyperparameters, let's say learning rate or regularization in real time during a TensorFlow simulation.

Something like: You are monitoring the cost function of your neural net(NN) and then you decide that your NN could be doing better if you reduce the regularization term. 
But you would like to do this without interrupting everything. Just typing the new value in somewhere and then changing the regularization in the next epoch, for example.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. If you save your model using a `saver()` object then you can do exactly what you describe, manually.

Comment: I know how to do it in keras. You can loop say for example 30 epochs. After each epochs keras model returns history object which has accuracy and other infor. Then based on that info before starting next epoch you can set optimizer/regularization in model object.

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare your hyper parameters has `placeholder` or a not trainable `Variable`, and change them as you need it using the `feed_dict`.

```
lr = tf.get_variable('learning_rate',initializer=tf.constant(1), trainable=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(lr)) # prints 1
    print(sess.run(lr, {lr: 10})) # prints 10
```

Comment: What about input size, hidden size, number of layers and many others? I don't think it is possible to change these hyperparameters during training in Tensorflow.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible because this would induce a modification of the graph.